# PyTorch - a functional equivalent of nn.Module

Tags: python, pytorch

As we know we can wrap arbitrary number of stateful building blocks into a class which inherits from `nn.Module`. But how is it supposed to be done when you want to wrap a bunch of stateless functions (from `nn.Functional`), in order to fully utilize things which `nn.Module` allows you to, like automatic moving of tensors between CPU and GPU with just `model.to(device)`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're referring to?

Comment: If you have a tensor (let's say `x`) and you want another tensor `y` to be transfered to the same device you can use `y = y.to(x)`. Not sure if this answers your question though.

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution: if you have an operation inside of a module which creates a new tensor, then you have to use `self.register_buffer` in order to fully utilize automating moving between devices.